# Перенос сайта WP на новый домен

Tags: wordpress

Доброго времени суток.

Ситуация следующая - перенес сайт на новый домен. Создал поддомен, создал БД, перенес все файлы и БД со старого домена, через srdb поменял ссылки, но сайт не открывается на новом домене, а перебрасывает на старый.

Если открыть сайт в окне инкогнито, он грузится, но без стилей.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что могло быть сделано не так? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Маловероятно, но может помочь: настройки->постоянные ссылки->сохранить (просто заходите нажимаете сохранить и всё), еще как вариант можно перенести сайт с помощью плагина Duplicator. Крайне маловероятно: обновить страницу так: зажимаете ctrl+shift и нажимаете R

Comment: скрин с таблицы options можно, что там записано в строках siteurl и home?